# Can a member class inherit from it's parent?

Tags: c++, oop

While considering "creative" (ie bizarre) solutions to an odd problem, one particular idea triggered my curiosity. It's not an idea I'm likely to use, but I'd still like to know if it's legal according to the standard.

A simple example would be...

```
class base_t
{
  private:
    //  stuff

  public:
    //  more stuff

    class derived_t : public base_t  //  <--- weirdness here
    {
      //  ...
    };      
};
```

Part of the weirdness - since `derived_t` inherits from `base_t` which contains `derived_t`, it seems like `derived_t` contains itself.

So - is this a valid-but-strange-and-scary thing of a similar kind to the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), or is it illegal?

**EDIT** - I should perhaps mention that the reason I thought of this was trying to avoid some namespace pollution. Having a class as a member avoids introducing another global class, but that second class needs to share a lot from the first.

If it was just one pair of classes it wouldn't be an issue, but this is for a code generator.

Comment: Just think about it. Think about a box that contains itself...

Comment: From an OOP perspective this is at least useless...

Comment: @Bruno: Not necessarily.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you want to access members from base_t in derived_t?

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant - I have pairs of classes that are about as closely related as normal iterators and reverse iterators, being generated in pairs. Some of the methods have an inverted sense to them, but otherwise almost everything is identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's legal, but maybe not the way you arranged your code.  A base class has to be complete at the point when it's used, but isn't until the closing brace of the definition.  So try forward-declaring the nested class:

```
class base_t
{
  private:
    //  stuff

  public:
    //  more stuff

    class derived_t;
};

class base_t::derived_t : public base_t
{
  //  ...
};
```

Comment: now i'm starting wondering about the completeness of derived class CRTP. there's something subtle here methinks.

Comment: @Alf: Well, the class *is* complete within member functions due to a two-phase processing.  Maybe that applies to nested type definitions  also.  For CRTP, though, a template parameter doesn't have to be complete, and a template based on an incomplete class isn't necessarily incomplete.